# getting unique records across time when a value changes SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

Still using 2008.  I have the following two tables and need to be able to pull out the individuals when, for a given date, the code is d for the first time.  It is easy to get those who are d who have never been e, but I can't figure out how to include the individuals the first time they are d if a previous e.  I have tried using a with to generate a list of all the es and than match it in with the others but have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to tie it to the other query.

```
Table1                                            Table2
Person  date1  date2  date3  date4  date5  date6  Person  FirstServ
1         e             e      d      d      d      1         date1
2                e      e                    d      2         date2
3                              d      d      d      3         date4
4                              d      d             4         date4
5         e                    d      d      d      5         date1
6         e      e                    d      d      6         date1
7                e      e      d      d      d      7         date2
8                              d      d      d      8         date4
9                              d      d             9         date4
10                             d      d      d     10         date4
```

Current code without bringing in the with clause is (and yes I know I am not necessarily the most efficient coder :) )

```
declare @myorder int
set @myorder = (select academicOrder from DimTermYear dt3 where termID='14/FA');

with myDual as (
select distinct ds.STTR_STUDENT, dt.academicOrder
    from dbo.DimStudentTerms ds 
        left join DimTermYear dt on dt.termID=ds.STTR_TERM 
    where ds.STTR_STU_CURRENT_TYPE = 'DE'
)


Select distinct sa.STC_PERSON_ID,ds2.STTR_STU_CURRENT_TYPE,dt2.academicOrder
    from StudentAcadCredFrom2000 sa
        left join dbo.DimStudentTerms ds2 on ds2.STTR_STUDENT=sa.STC_PERSON_ID
        left join DimTermYear dt2 on dt2.termID=ds2.STTR_TERM 
    where (sa.STC_CURRENT_STATUS in ('A','N') or (STC_CURRENT_STATUS='D' and STC_GRADE IS NOT NULL))
    and sa.STC_TERM='14/FA' and ds2.D04_FIRST_TERM_ENR='14/FA'
    and ds2.STTR_STU_CURRENT_TYPE='DS' and dt2.academicOrder=@myorder
order by sa.STC_PERSON_ID
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match up with the example data you provided. Please adjust one or the other to clarify your intentions.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit dnoeth, I was working to get it correct but you beat me to it!

Comment: Synergist, This is my first post so I will see what I can do, was just using the tables as examples of the base problem.  I realize having the full data might be more helpful, thought I would just throw in my code in case that helped.  I apologize if this has made it more confusing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in Table 2, you want Person 1 and 5 to have a `FirstServ` value of `date4`, correct?

Comment: The bottom code gives me a list of people who are "d" for the first time that have never been served.  I need to add to this list those people who were served earlier under other codes but have switched to the "d" code for the first time in the same term as in the bottom code.

Comment: I can't change the value of FirstServ, would need 1, 5 and 7 added to my list for date 4, the list without these from the bottom code would have 3,4,8,9,10 in it

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that Table 1 will only have 6 date columns (`date1` through `date6`), then you can just use a series of cases as follows:

```
with temp as (
    select Person, firstDateOfD = (
        CASE WHEN date1 = 'd' THEN date1
        CASE WHEN date2 = 'd' THEN date2
        CASE WHEN date3 = 'd' THEN date3
        CASE WHEN date4 = 'd' THEN date4
        CASE WHEN date5 = 'd' THEN date5
        CASE WHEN date6 = 'd' THEN date6)
    from Table1
) 
-- create your lists as you need.
-- e.g. date1_list = select Person from temp where firstDateOfD = date1
```